# form onsubmit inline javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, submit, inline

I am trying to put an inline onsubmit script on a form, but it's not working:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <form onsubmit="(function(event){console.log(event); return false;})(this);">
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

And is the parameter for the function the event or the form element?

Comment: In the inline JS, `this` is the form, not the event.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In inline Javascript, `this` is always the element itself. `event` is available as a variable local to the inline Javascript, so you can write:

```
<form onsubmit="return (function(event){console.log(event); return false;})(event);">
```

Since you're using an IIFE, its `return` statement returns from the function, but not from the event handler. You need to return what the IIFE returns.

I'm not sure why you're using an IIFE, you can just write:

```
<form onsubmit="console.log(event); return false;">
```

Comment: I can't test right now, but are you sure *event* is global in Firefox? I seem to recall that it was a property of *window* in IE, which was adopted by some other browsers, but not Firefox (or Mozilla browsers generally), hence the frequent use of `function foo(evt){evt = evt || window.event}`.

Comment: it's not a global generally, but it's available inside the inline Javascript.